# How to get rid of Merge commits in git

Tags: git, merge, git-commit

I have a repository which is shared by more than 1 person So often I see there are a lot of merge commits in commit history. I want to get rid of them to make my commit history to look cleaner.

What is the practice we should follow to avoid these merge commits? Is it doable ?

I read about merging using `--ff-only` switch. Can this switch help me ?

Comment: Example of a rebase workflow: http://randyfay.com/content/rebase-workflow-git - also, for the clean history, `git log` has a `--no-merges` switch that omits merge commits.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of merge commits? Or, why do you consider an accurate history with merge commits "unclean". Merging is a natural activity in a multi-user repository and accurately recording development activity, including merge activities, should be a positive thing.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Some part of me also wanted to ask if there is a practice which should be used to avoid merge commits and if It is right to avoid merge commits. Thanks for tip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `--ff-only` can only make `git merge` fail if cannot be resolved as a fast-forward, but failing a merge does not solve the problem.

To avoid having too many merge commits, use `git rebase`.

See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing to know how rebase works.

Answer (score 11):

If you have your local changes which are not pushed to remote yet, and if you pull latest updates from remote it will create a merge commit. To avoid this try

```
git pull --rebase
```

Answer (score 3):

I have got one more approach to avoid merge commits. This is what I am following now.

1. Before making any commit, always pull latest code from your upstream.
2. Sometimes, it may say please commit your changes/stash them and will not let you get the latest commits. This is because you have edited some file and which was also edited in one of the commits in upstream. So stash your changes using `git stash`
3. Again use `git pull origin master`
4. This time, there won't be any problem and you have the latest code from upstream. Now, regain your code from stash using `git stash apply`
5. There might be some automerge conflict, resolve them and make your commit and push to server using `git push origin master`

There might be a case, that during process of merging and making commit, someone else also makes a commit on upstream/server. In this case, your push will fail and ask you to pull code from server/upstream again. If you pull instantly, you will be a victim of merge commit. So to avoid this use `git reset head^`

Don't worry your code won't get lost and now you are again back to Step 0. Follow the same steps again. You are good to go.

Comment: git stash pop may be better than git stash apply as pop will also remove the stach from the stack of stashes otherwise your workflow will mean the stack of stashes just keeps growing.

Comment: @darran I agree... We should use git stash pop most of the time unless I know that I can reuse the changes later.. Like some conifg change... Where user may want to use git stash apply